# working with temporary tables in Joomla 2.5

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am trying to use MySql temporary tables with my joomla site.
the problem is that whenever I query about the content of the table I get an empty result (except when using select statement in the same function where I create the table).

My questions are:

- everytime I use `$db = JFactory::getDBO()` - do I create a new DB connection?
- if so - how can I use temporary files?
- if not - why don't I get the data of the temp table?

How can I create a temporary table that will remain until the user logs out?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use temporary tables like this, read the docs on temporary tables in MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html). The table will be deleted on each session, which will probably be each page load, possibly sooner, depending on how this is handled throughout Joomla.

If you want your temporary table to persist, you need to create normal table, not a temporary table...

Comment: I have read the mySql docs, but it is not clear 
- the temp tables exists durin the saem connection, BUT - how does Joomla handle connections?  -how can I use the same connection in different pages ?

As for using real tables - the problem is I will need to create one for every user, and that seems like a bad idea...

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a bad idea to create one for every user, and probably better to adapt so you can do it in a  single table. Anyway, joomla will not reuse connections between page calls like you want.

Comment: thx.
in that case my question would be - is it better to create temp tables in every relevant page or use a more complex query every time?